# C# DataContext returns null on comparing dates

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating a database based desktop application and stuck in a problem..Actually I am new to Linq...

```
if (OP == "Delete")
            {
                tb = DB.TblPurchase.FirstOrDefault(e => e.PID.Equals(ID) || e.PItemName.Equals(ItemName) || e.PCategory.Equals(Category) || e.PDate.Equals(Date)); // returns null on comparing date

                DB.Delete(tb);

                return "Deleted";
            }
            else if (OP == "Search")
            {
                tb = DB.TblPurchase.FirstOrDefault(e => e.PID.Equals(ID) || e.PItemName.Equals(ItemName) || e.PCategory.Equals(Category) || e.PDate == Date);  // returns null on comparing date as well

                return tb;
            }
```

Starting of the function :

```
`public object AUDS_Purchase(string OP, int? ID = null, string ItemName = "",string Category = "", string Supplier = "", DateTime? Date = null, int ? Rate = null, int? Quantity = null, int? Total = null)
        {
            using(var DB = new MYDBDB())
            {
                TblPurchase tb = null;`
```

Calling the function :

```
`dynamic _ID = Cmb_Search_ItemID.SelectedIndex == -1 ? null : Cmb_Search_ItemID.SelectedValue;
            dynamic _ItemName = Cmb_Search_ItemName.SelectedIndex == -1 ? null : Cmb_Search_ItemName.SelectedValue.ToString();
            dynamic _ItemCategory = Cmb_Search_ItemCategory.SelectedIndex == -1 ? null : Cmb_Search_ItemCategory.SelectedValue.ToString();
            dynamic _Date = Search_Item_Date;

            dynamic res;

            if (Search_Item_Date.Checked == false)
            {
                if (_ID != null || _ItemName != null || _ItemCategory != null)
                {
                    res = tb.AUDS_Inventory("Search", Convert.ToInt32(_ID), _ItemName, _ItemCategory);

                    tb.ShowNewData(metroGrid1, res);
                }
                else
                {

                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "No Value Given\nSelect a value", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                res = tb.AUDS_Inventory("Search", Convert.ToInt32(_ID), _ItemName, _ItemCategory, Date:_Date);

                tb.ShowNewData(metroGrid1, res);
            }`
```

**Note : I am sure tb is null because I used breakpoint...**

My table contains the records : [Picture prove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjcJW.png)

Everything works fine with the database and the table...

This is my first post BTW..
Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include details of the error and which line is giving you this error.

Comment: Thanks sir for replying and link...check the comments given on the first code "if (OP == "Delete")"

Answer (score 1):

If the Date you are providing in the function contains different time then that might be the cause. As I can see from your database picture you are trying to compare date only. So you can try excluding time, it might work. You can try
`e.PDate.Date == Date.Date` in your function.

Comment: You can try checking your function by providing direct value. You can also try checking out what date is actually being passed to the function.

Comment: I checked the date is passing correctly (It is actually passing with time but as per my experience it doesn't matter) .... would you like to come with teamviewer to view the code...?